# Prevent HorizontalScrollView to be accessed from anywhere on the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I made (in Android Studio) a HorizontalScrollView which I can access from anywhere on the screen, meaning that where ever I scroll, be it on the top or the bottom of the screen, the ScrollView which is in the middle gets scrolled.

This is the code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post all of the code of this layout, although I might suggest using a specific height for horizontalSerollView to protect it from match_parent or wrap_content and use RelativeLayout as child.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="your_height(not match_parent)"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your layout wrap_content, for example:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="140dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         />
  </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Specifying height for horizontalSerollView. It protects from match_parent or wrap_content which causes layout crash or no result. RelativeLayout is most preferred for this because of the placement of views.